# angularjs : different meta tags for each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2, web-crawler

i have developed website by using ruby on rails and angularjs(with JS and Jquery).I just want to know that Is it possible to have different meta tags for each page in angularjs?? According to me any crawler detects only the meta tags generated by server side.so please help me if this is possible in angularjs or not.

Thanks,

Comment: Crawlers do not execute JavaScript, so you do not need to think about meta tags when change page content with Angular.

Comment: @TheHippo : - as per our SEO experts we should have meta tags and description displayed on the final HTML also. Currently we have explained the logic displaying the same content via escape fragment url, but we want to display the same on final HTML which is rendered to user i.e whenever we do a view page source, we should be able to see meta-tag and description. How can this be achieved if I have many pages on my website and meta-tags need to be different for all the pages.

Comment: You would need to use some pre-rendering service like https://prerender.io to allow search engines to crawl your pages. As for changing the meta tags for each page, I suggest a directive with event listeners which inject different meta based on the current page.